# Issue with reverse coding in R tidyr

Tags: r, tidyverse, recode

This is my code:*

```
data %>%
  mutate(r_stemster_3 = recode(stemster_3,
                               `1` = 7,
                               `2` = 6, 
                               `3` = 5,
                               `4` = 4, 
                               `5` = 3,
                               `6` = 2,
                               `7` = 1))
```

This is the error message:

```
Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `r_stemster_3 = recode(...)`.
Caused by error in `recode()`:
! unused arguments (`1` = 7, `2` = 6, `3` = 5, `4` = 4, `5` = 3, `6` = 2, `7` = 1)
Backtrace:
 1. data %>% ...
 3. dplyr:::mutate.data.frame(...)
 4. dplyr:::mutate_cols(.data, dplyr_quosures(...), by)
 6. dplyr:::mutate_col(dots[[i]], data, mask, new_columns)
 7. mask$eval_all_mutate(quo)
 8. dplyr (local) eval()

Error in mutate(., r_stemster_3 = recode(stemster_3, `1` = 7, `2` = 6,  : 
  
Caused by error in `recode()`:
! unused arguments (`1` = 7, `2` = 6, `3` = 5, `4` = 4, `5` = 3, `6` = 2, `7` = 1)
```

I can't figure out what was wrong with my code. Please help fix the code!

I tried variations of the code such as removing the backticks or using single/double quotes instead of backticks. None of them worked.

Also data$stemster_3 is numeric and I want the reverse coded variable to be numeric too.

Comment: `8 - data$r_stemster_3`

Comment: Hi, I believe that you may have a package that changed the definition of the recode function. Either load the tidyverse package before running the code or replace `recode` with `dplyr::recode`. If you are running both the `car` and `dplyr` package, this is most likely the issue

Comment: You are right @Cravetheflame. The issue lies in the packages. After I removed car, the codes worked perfectly. Thank you so much!

Comment: Happy to help, but please consider @Onyambu's answer as it demonstrates a simpler way of dealing with what you were trying to do :)

Comment: Note more "scalable" extension of Onyambu's answer would be `(max(data$r_stemster_3)+1) - data$r_stemster_3`

Comment: Thank you so much @Onyambu and @jpsmith! I'll start to use the simpler codes!

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to deal with reverse coding in R. Here are some:

1. The simplest way

```
sampledf <- data.frame(V1 = c(1, 4, 5, 6, 7),
                       V2 = c(2, 4, 4, 5, 6),
                       V3 = c(2, 7, 1, 1, 5))
8 - sampledf
```

2. 'psych' package

```
sampledf <- data.frame(V1 = c(1, 4, 5, 6, 7),
                       V2 = c(2, 4, 4, 5, 6),
                       V3 = c(2, 7, 1, 1, 5))

install.packages("psych")
library(psych)
reverseitems <- c(-1, 1, 1)
reverse.code(reverseitems, sampledf, mini = 1, maxi = 7)
```

note. `reverseitems <- c(-1, 1, 1)` is here to indicate `V1` in the dataset. In this case, only the values in the first column will be reverse-coded.

3. 'dplyr' package

```
sampledf <- data.frame(V1 = c(1, 4, 5, 6, 7),
                       V2 = c(2, 4, 4, 5, 6),
                       V3 = c(2, 7, 1, 1, 5))
library(dplyr)
sampledf |> 
  mutate(new = 8 - sampledf)
```

note. In this way, new variables will be added to the dataset (`sampledf`).

4. `apply()` function

```
sampledf <- data.frame(V1 = c(1, 4, 5, 6, 7),
                       V2 = c(2, 4, 4, 5, 6),
                       V3 = c(2, 7, 1, 1, 5))
sample123 <- apply(sampledf[, c(1, 2, 3)], 2, function(x) 8-x)
sample123
```

note. By using `c(1, 2, 3)` you can specify the variables (eg. all variables). After having new dataset, you can merge the specific variables of the old and new datasets (`data.frame()` function).